# How does one sketch a proof to show that the following problem is in the P Complexity Class?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete

[image]

I have the following problem. I do not know where to start or how I should approach this problem. I am not sure about how to prove if a problem is in a complexity class of P . I know how to do NP but P confuses me.

Comment: In order to prove that a problem is in P, you just have to come up with an efficient algorithm for solving the problem (running in polynomial time). So all you have to do is to come up with an efficient algorithm that determines whether a given CNF is a tautology.

Comment: so like an algorithm to check if each conjuct is either true or false

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So to prove that the following problem is in $\mathcal{P}$, we need to construct an algorithm that solves the problem in polynomial time.

First we analyse the problem. We know that we are given $n$ boolean expressions of the form $$C_1 \land C_2 \land \dots \land C_n $$ with $C_i$  a disjunction of literals.

So the solve this problem, we reduce it by first analyzing whether each $C_i$ is true or false. Then we save the boolean of each $C_i$ in a list. This list will now contain the boolean of each $C_i$. All we have to do now is to check if the conjuction of all the elements inside this list is true or false. A conjunction is false iff there exists only one element in the list that is false. Thus if we find one single element that is false, we return false, otherwise we return true.

Below you can find a high level algorithm.

Lets say that $C_1 \land C_2 \land \dots \land C_n $ = $C_{total}$

[image: algorithm]

If $n$ is the number of elements in $C_{total}$ and $m$ is the average number of elements in $C_i$, the complexity of this algorithm is $\mathcal{O}(n*m)$, which is polynomial.

I hope this helped you out, let me know if you have any question in the comments below.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation